# Update all geometry points by adding/subtracting from XY

Tags: mysql, spatial, geometry

I want to update the POINT geometry column for all rows in a table.

For example, I want to change POINT(1 1) to POINT(1.1 .9)

```
UPDATE myTable SET geoPoint = asText(geoPointX+1 geoPoint Y-1)
```

The query is example of what I want to achieve, but I'm unsure how to split the text and then handle the values.

Answer (score 1):

This makes absolutely no sense, but you would want to do something like this

```
UPDATE myTable
  SET geoPoint = Point( ST_X(geoPoint)+0.1, ST_Y(geoPoint)-0.1 );
```

This will move absolutely in the base unit of the SRS.

Answer (score 0):

this way not ok in speed and Accuracy if you seperate x and y new fild better than.

```
UPDATE myTable SET geoPoint_x = :x ,  geoPoint_y = :y where geoPoint_id = :id
```

i use the :x and :y for example .

if you need to split text , you must split in in web server or in frontend jquery and send just x,y to database